# Pass javascript object via generated link to modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have generated a tag via Javascript and I want to pass a 'js object' to this receiver. This is the  generated code:

```
toReturn += "<a class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\" data-task-info=\"" + data + "\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#taskInfoModal\"></a>";
```

But here my object data became a string and I lose my data. I want to retrieve them in the called modal, like this:

```
$('#taskInfoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var link = $(event.relatedTarget);
   var taskInfo = link.data('task-info');
   var modal = $(this);
   modal.find('.modal-body').html(taskInfo);
   console.log(taskInfo);
});
```

Comment: try this toReturn += '<a class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\" data-task-info=\"' + data + '\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#taskInfoModal\"></a>';

Comment: It's the same man, it doesn't work.